# What is the best way to formulate a question containing CPU comparison elements?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted a [question containing CPU comparison elements](https://superuser.com/questions/465372/which-of-an-amd-or-intel-desktop-cpu-will-perform-better-when-running-6-8-virt) and it was closed within minutes as not constructive. I agree that the way it is formulated opens a door to a flame/camp war and that was not my intention. I am genuinely interested in recent benchmarks and personal feedback from people running a setup similar to the one described in the question. I am looking for technical advice about the best CPU for this kind of virtualization setup. I am not looking for a shopping recommendation although it is true I would have to eventually buy said CPU.

What would be the best way to reformulate the question? Should I remove AMD and Intel from the title and question text? Should I put links to the articles I have read so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question should focus on how to choose, not what to choose.

Example:

> Instead of asking:
>
> ```
> Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?
> A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
> ```
>
> Ask this instead:
>
> ```
> Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos? 
> A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
>
>     a fast lens (2.0 at least)
>     reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
>     the biggest sensor available
>
> The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try that!